# How can I grab a clicked word in an iframe src with js?

Tags: javascript, iframe, getselection

This js allows copying a clicked word in an html element to var "str". But I want to grab a word in an iframe src. I modified the js to target the iframe id #USCF_CUST and grab the  clicked word, but it doesn't seem to work. The clicked word is not selected and copied to var "str". **Can anyone tell me why?**

```
<div class = "clickable">The rain in Spain falls mainly in the plane.</div>

 $(".clickable").click(function(e) {
 s = window.getSelection(); var range = s.getRangeAt(0); var node = s.anchorNode;
 while (range.toString().indexOf(' ') != 0) {range.setStart(node, (range.startOffset - 1));}
 range.setStart(node, range.startOffset + 1);
 do {range.setEnd(node, range.endOffset + 1);}
 while (range.toString().indexOf(' ') == -1 && range.toString().trim() != '');
 str = range.toString().trim(); alert (str);
});
```

But the above js doesn't work (it does nothing) in this instance:

```
<iframe id = 'USCF_CUST' src= url_2 ></iframe>

 $("#USCF_CUST").click(function(e) {
 s = window.getSelection(); var range = s.getRangeAt(0); var node = s.anchorNode;
 while (range.toString().indexOf(' ') != 0) {range.setStart(node, (range.startOffset - 1));}
 range.setStart(node, range.startOffset + 1);
 do {range.setEnd(node, range.endOffset + 1);}
 while (range.toString().indexOf(' ') == -1 && range.toString().trim() != '');
 str = range.toString().trim(); alert (str);
});
```

Comment: Is the `<iframe>` a same-origin or cross-origin iframe? Does anything appear in your browser console? (and why are you using jQuery in 2022?)

Comment: The <iframe> is of my domain (same origin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `window` you reference the window where the code is executed. However, it seems like you want to reference `iframe`s `window`.

Try using [`contentWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow) property of iframe in order to set listeners, `getSelection`, etc.

It will only work if the [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) of both pages is exactly the same.

Comment: "It will only work if the domain of both pages is exactly the same." - not just the domain, 
but the entire [Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) tuple must match: the URI scheme (i.e. `https` vs `http`), domain/hostname or host address, and the port number (it's only cookies that are partitioned by domain-name due to historical legacy, pretty much everything else is origin-based).

Comment: @Dai Yep, you're right, I've edited the answer. It might also work in some cases if you do tricks with [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain), but hopefully it'll be totally deprecated & removed soon